# Why intercept not equal to dependent var. mean after Centering: rstanarm package

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian

Package `rstanarm` in `R`, by default, centers the predictor variables. But I'm wondering in the case of a simple linear regression below, why intercept is not equal to dependent var. mean after Centering?

## Here is my R code and data:

```
cor.norm <- function(x, r, m = 95, s = 4){
  e  = rnorm(length(x), m, s)
  return(y = round(r*x + e))
}

prof <- {                 # dataset “prof”
set.seed(1170)  
data.frame(LAA = LAA <- round(rnorm(60, 32, 4)), TOEFL = cor.norm(LAA, .3) )
}

library(rstanarm)
     fit <- stan_glm(TOEFL ~ LAA, data = prof,            
                       prior_intercept = normal(0, 10),   # prior on intercept (α)
                                 prior = normal(0, 2.5),  # prior on slope (β)
                             prior_aux = cauchy(0, 100))  # prior on sd (σ)

summary(fit) # HERE, intercept ≠ mean of TOEFL

# Intercept (α)     88.84
# mean(prof$TOEFL)  103.5833
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it uncenters at the end so that the intercept corresponds to the `glm` parameterization. You want to be looking at the mean (over the observations) of the prior predictive distribution that is listed at the bottom of the `print` method output to make sure that it corresponds to the sample mean of the outcome, but it always does in Gaussian, no link, linear models.